# Formatting R output

Tags: r

The summary function in R gives an output as follows

```
         Variable 1
 Min.   :-2.192e+09                         
 1st Qu.:0.000e+00                         
 Median :2.632e+05                         
 Mean   :7.933e+06                        
 3rd Qu.:4.668e+06                        
 Max.   :1.124e+09                         
 NA's   :277
```

I want to get an output in the following format:

```
            Min  1st Qu  Median  Mean  3rd Qu  Max  NA's
Variable 1   -     -      -       -      -      -    -

Variable 2   -     -      -       -      -      -    -
```

How can I do that and export to Excel?

Comment: Check the `?t` documentation

Comment: `write.csv2(broom::tidy(summary(1:100)), file = "yay.csv")`

Answer (score 3):

If I'm right, you want to write summary information of vectors to Excel? If so, this might work for you (package *readr* required, or you may use `write.csv()`):

```
tmp <- data.frame(
  var1 = runif(100, min = 5, max = 50),
  var2 = c(runif(99, min = 50, max = 150), NA),
  var3 = runif(100, min = 150, max = 250)
)

tmp <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, lapply(tmp, function(x) {
  # save summary information
  v <- as.vector(summary(x))
  # if vector has no NAs, manually add 0, to ensure equal 
  # length of vectors for column bind
  if (length(v) < 7) v <- c(v, 0)
  # return summary
  v
}))))

colnames(tmp) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.", "NA's")

# result so far:
##         Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu.   Max. NA's
## var1   5.097   15.12  26.83  26.46   36.89  49.75    0
## var2  50.900   83.08 104.50 103.80  129.00 149.20    1
## var3 151.200  166.80 200.30 197.00  223.70 248.50    0

readr::write_excel_csv(tmp, "summary.csv")
```